# React Native app crash Error on Androids: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}

Tags: java, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Firebase returned with crash error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
> java.util.Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:220)

I believe this is related to Google sign in, but my app does not implement Google sign in anywhere so am not sure if the android user was able to somehow get their phone to prompt them with a google sign in option. My app instead uses react-native-firebase/auth

I did the following to troubleshoot this:

- Double-check your React Native codebase to ensure that you have not inadvertently included or attempted to use Google Sign-In functionality without proper setup.
- Look for any calls to Google Sign-In methods, imports related to authentication, or components that might be triggering the Google Sign-In flow.
- Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and look for any declarations related to Google Sign-In components or activities. Ensure that these entries are valid and necessary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.